# Azure function is getting executed in local even RunOnStartup = false

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

As per my understanding Azure function will execute

In case **RunOnStartup = true**

```
   1. on startup 
   2. if a host changed 
   3. a new deployment happen
   4. on schedule time
```

And, In case **RunOnStartup = false or not define**

```
   1. on schedule time only
```

but when I am running it locally with **RunOnStartup = false**, it is executing on startup as well and on azure portal it is working fine. Can anyone please suggest why it happen?

update:-
Function code:-

```csharp
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 30 3 * * *", RunOnStartup = false)]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext executionContext)
    {
        log.Info($"Function1- Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        try
        {
            //main work
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            log.Info($"Function1 - Timer trigger function ENDED at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
```

Console output:-

```
   your worker runtime is not set. As of 2.0.1-beta.26 a worker runtime setting is
```

required.
Please run `func settings add FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME <option>` or add FUNCTION
S_WORKER_RUNTIME to your local.settings.json
Available options: dotnet, node, python

```
              %%%%%%
             %%%%%%
        @   %%%%%%    @
      @@   %%%%%%      @@
   @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
 @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
   @@         %%%%       @@
     @@      %%%       @@
       @@    %%      @@
            %%
            %

  Azure Functions Core Tools (2.3.148 Commit hash:     f9b3db04f9833b431f1b001efb3e5783a169ebfc)
  Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12210.0
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM] Building host: startup suppressed:False, configuration suppressed: False
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM] Reading host configuration file 'D:\path****\host.json'
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM] Host configuration file read:
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM] {
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM]   "version": "2.0"
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM] }
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM] Initializing Host.
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM] Starting JobHost
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM] Starting Host (HostId=boldsombirk-85417686, InstanceId=4f41b83d-022e-4e75-b75b-528890f62058, Version=2.0.12210.0, ProcessId=7012, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:47 AM] Loading functions metadata
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:48 AM] 1 functions loaded
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:48 AM] Generating 1 job function(s)
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:48 AM] Found the following functions:
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:48 AM] Function1.Run
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:48 AM]
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:48 AM] Host initialized (673ms)
  [19-Dec-18 8:22:49 AM] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='Timer fired at 2018-12-19T13:52:49.5718606+05:30', Id=e1603f8f-41d0-492e-8674-d5771813422d)
  [19-Dec-18 8:23:41 AM] Function1 - Timer trigger function executed at: 19-Dec-18 1:53:41 PM
```

Comment: Please add some more relevant information like source code and configuration. With the current information, we can't help you. One specific question: when you startup the Function locally, it tells you what its next runtimes will be. Could you post that information/the console output too?

Comment: If you have any confusion about my explanation, just ask. If it does help could you accept it for more people to refer?

Answer (score 10):

Let's start with an example, a timer trigger starts with `0 */5 * * * *` schedule at `12/19/2018 4:01:00 PM`, and we can see the schedule print

```
12/19/2018 4:05:00 PM
12/19/2018 4:10:00 PM
12/19/2018 4:15:00 PM
12/19/2018 4:20:00 PM
12/19/2018 4:25:00 PM
```

However, we stop(debugging) the project at `4:02 PM`. And then run it again at `4:08 PM`, we can see timer trigger execute on startup.

This happens because the ScheduleStatus(as below) has been stored in blob storage the first time the trigger starts. When we run the project again, timer trigger reads existing `Next` scheduled time and compares it with current time. If the scheduled `Next` moment has passed, timer trigger executes immediately on startup.

```json
 // I am in UTC+8:00 time zone
{
    "Last":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Next":"2018-12-19T16:05:00+08:00",
    "LastUpdated":"2018-12-19T16:02:12.7071566+08:00"
}
```

Follow [the sample in doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#c-example) to handle execution for outdated schedule. The `IsPastDue` property is true when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.

```csharp
[FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    if(myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Timer is running late!");
    }
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes the behavior pretty clear. To avoid it, though, is it as easy as moving the "Next" time to the next planned execution rather than allowing a past due execution?

Comment: @Blue "moving the 'Next' time to next planned execution", I am not sure it's a good idea because the timer info is supposed to be completely handled by function runtime. Why not just leave the function do nothing if (myTimer.isPastDue == true)?

Answer (score 1):

Jerry's answer is the correct one, but if you want quick fix when testing code with RunOnStartup then you can just change current Timer trigger to time in future.

Example : In your case change it from `0 30 3 * * *` to `0 30 23 * * *`.

Note : This is not a recommended practice. Outdated schedule must be handled.